# Cannot move Linux Wifi Driver into the specific directory

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, mv

I am currently trying to put the driver's folder into the WiFi directory but it is giving me a error every time I execute it.

The instructions on the website are super vague on what to do step by step
sudo mv /Home/Downloads/wifi_driver/ /lib/modules/5.4.0-54-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/

```
mv: cannot stat '/Home/Downloads/wifi_driver/': No such file or directory
```

Output:

```
lsusb

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 003 Device 007: ID 2357:0106 TP-Link Archer T9UH v1 [Realtek 
RTL8814AU]

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 017: ID 04e8:6863 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy series, misc. (tethering mode)

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:1939 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AURA LED Controller

Bus 001 Device 020: ID 046d:c53d Logitech, Inc. USB Receiver

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: We don't know what OS & release you are talking about?  Your details also look incorrect (is "Downloads" your username? - this will be your issue (/Home is also not a standard directory; do you mean  `/home/` ?) but your question is vague without specifics)

Comment: Sorry about that! For the Operating System, I am using Ubuntu Version 20.04, and the WiFi adapter is the TP Link AC1900. Also 'Downloads' is not the username that I am using, its the directory of where the driver's folder is located.

Comment: Frankly, the instructions look very wrong to me and inconsistent with generally accepted practices.. May we see a link to the driver and instructions?

Comment: If I was to download a file using a browser (I'm guessing here, I don't download that way), I would expect it to be saved in `/home/guiverc/Downloads/ ; which is very different to the "/Home/Downloads/" you mentioned.  /home and /Home are different directories (case matters!) and you have Downloads where usually the username is....

Comment: https://static.tp-link.com/2018/201812/20181207/Installation%20Guide%20for%20Linux.pdf  Another thing that should be noted is that as I was reading the instructions, I got I stuck on the part where it said to execute the 'Make clean' command and it outputted:  'make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.'

Comment: I am quite confident that there is a much better way. Let's start by identifying your exact device. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb`

Comment: I installed the driver from the website and I extracted and moved it into the Downloads directory

Comment: We don't see your adapter in `lsusb`. Is it a PCI device? If so, please add: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

Comment: Fixed it! It was connected to a different cord for showing up on the lsusb

Comment: However, it is still not showing up in the settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ID 2357:0106 TP-Link Archer T9UH v1 [Realtek RTL8814AU]

Your device is driven by the driver rtl8814au, as the name suggests. With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential git dkms
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8814au.git
cd rtl8814au
sudo make dkms_install
```

Remove and reinsert the device and your wireless should now be working.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got It to work now

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working. If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour